# iOS 6.0 iAd deprecation problems

Tags: xcode, ios6, iad, deprecated

Anybody know what to use to replace requiredContentSizeIdentifiers, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait & currentContentSizeIdentifier for ios 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Dave123  As of iOS 6.0, the banner will automatically resize itself based on its width.
 To support iOS 5.0 however, we continue to set the currentContentSizeIdentifier appropriately.
as

CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    if (contentFrame.size.width < contentFrame.size.height) {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }

just code as you are using ios 5.0 and in ios 6.0 it will do all other work it own self.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following line of Code

```
            TabAdvert.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
```

(With Tab Advert being the name of you BannerAdView)